# bin/kafka-console-producer.sh Exception

Tags: apache-kafka, producer

when I typed this command line:
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test

But,the final result returns like this:

[image]

it returns nothing,it is unusual.Somebody could help?Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you do to achieve this? Show your code/efforts here.StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you have a problem with your code, please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.